# Catch exceptions when uploading files to google-cloud-storage bucket using python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, google-cloud-storage, try-except

I'm using the function below to upload local files to my google storage bucket. What is the proper way of catching all possible errors? I would like to use all and the most specific exceptions that might occur while attempting an upload.

How would I approach finding all the possible errors that might occur and implementing them?

```py
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_to_gcp(source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("some-bucket")
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

Comment: Your statement **finding all the possible errors** is not a good strategy. Python changes, libraries change, SDK errors change. Factor in that a library can create custom exceptions and you would have a serious problem achieving your requirement. Instead, review the SDK source code, note the major exceptions, and have a default catch for the others. Note: catching all exceptions is not a good strategy. Some exceptions require that the program abort execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch all exceptions, a simply try-except block will do it.

```
try:
   blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
   blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Now, if you want to have specific blocks for particular exceptions you might need to look at the GCS API errors list: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#standardcodes